# Using xlwt vs openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I need some help with openpyxl in PYTHON. I have been using xlwt quite successfully, but now I have some files (in MySQL Workbench) that contain more than 65,000 rows. I know I can create a CSV file, but XLSX is the preferred output. I am able to create a workbook using openpyxl, but I have not been successful placing the MySQL data into the table. The main portion of the program using xlwt is pretty straightforward (see below). I just cannot seem to figure out how to do the same thing using openpyxl. I've tried a number of different combinations and solutions. I just get stuck after the "for x in result:".

```
file_dest = "c:\home\test.xls"
result = dest.execute("select a, b, c, d from filea")
for x in result:
    rw = rw + 1
    sheet1 = book.add.sheet("Sheet 1")
    row1 = sheet1.row(rw)
    row1.write(1, x[0])
    row1.write(1, x[1])
    row1.write(1, x[2])
    row1.write(1, x[3])
book.save(file_dest)
```

Comment: It doesn't look like the code you've quoted is working `xlwt` code. I find it unlikely you want to create a new sheet for each row in the result set, and in any case the syntax wouldn't be `book.add.sheet`. But assuming that your *actual* code that you are *actually* running does successfully use `xlwt`, then you may be better off using `xlsxwriter` instead of `openpyxl` as `xlsxwriter` has a programming interface closer to that of `xlwt`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good use case for using [append()](http://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/api.html#openpyxl.worksheet.Worksheet.append):

> Appends a group of values at the bottom of the current sheet.
>
> If it’s a list: all values are added in order, starting from the first
>   column

```
import openpyxl

file_dest = "test.xlsx"

workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.get_active_sheet()

result = dest.execute("select a, b, c, d from filea")
for x in result:
    worksheet.append(list(x))

workbook.save(file_dest)
```

Comment: ALECXE - tried this solution, but I receive the error message "TypeError: list_or_dict must be a list or a dict".

Answer (score 1):

A little example:

```
wb = Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
row = 2
ws.title = "Report"
ws.cell('A1').value = "Value"
ws.cell('B1').value = "Note"
for item in results:
    ws.cell('A%d' % (row)).value = item[0]
    ws.cell('B%d' % (row)).value = item[1]
    row += 1
```

http://pythonhosted.org//openpyxl/

Comment: SILWESTPL - tried this solution and it is working - for the most part. I have a couple of very large files (+800,000 records) and it is taking an extremely long time to complete. Smaller files (+100,000) seem to process a little quicker.

Comment: For very large files where you are only wishing to dump the data then there is a flag for the `Workbook(optimized_write=True)` so that data will be written directly to the the Excel file. Otherwise everything gets converted into Python objects and kept in memory for manipulation. For pure speed when writing only `xlsxwriter` has the edge.